# Fallout shelter HUD goes away after i start the first quest

Tags: fallout-shelter

So, I recently got the overseers office, BUT when the helpful tips show up for starting quests, the HUD goes away permanently. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me once, I unistalled and then reinstalled it and it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Probably reinstalling would fix this. Its been occasionally buggy for me too. HUD numbers missing and all.

Word of caution: save your vaults into the cloud before reinstalling. Don't want to lose all those precious vault hours.